# How to properly show a popover?

Tags: ios, objective-c, popover

So I've linked one button (the one which represent a trash, in blue) with a second scene on my project as shown in the following link: https://gyazo.com/52f140f12cd5d80dd7e4ea191e8daa5f

**My problem:**
I don't know why, but my popover does not fully appear, see this picture:[image: The popover is cut]

**My question:**
Knowing that i'm actually working with the interface builder, how can i manage this popover so it will be fully displayed (it actual size are normally set as 500*500)?
Or do I have to do it programmatically? If yes, can someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how you create and present the popover.

Comment: What triggers the popover?

Comment: I dinde wrote any code, that's what I said, i'm (for the moment) only working with the interface builder.